# How to configure netty http client connection idle timeout for Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

We uses Spring Cloud Gateway for Authentication/Authorization and it's OAuth2 Authentication filter uses Netty http client to post request to Identify Provider. It appears that the load balancer often disconnects the connections (Channels) in the Netty connection pool. We are seeking the ways either disable that connection pool or set idle timeout to a limit time so that connection in the pool get disposed instead of load balancer to disconnect it.

What is the way in Spring Cloud Gateway or Spring WebFlux to do that since we are not create HTTP client in our application and it is Spring OAuth2 Authentication filter doing so?

We tried configure Spring Cloud Gateway HTTP Client parameters but it does not affect Netty HTTP Client which is used by Spring OAuth2 Authentication filter.